# PCI Compliance : Capture Credit Card, make ajax call to save address, then post of Payment Provider

Tags: pci-dss, credit-card, ajax, pci-scope

Say on the guest checkout page of an e-commerce website, if the user enters the delivery address, payment details (Credit card details) and clicks Submit button - and if

1. an ajax request is made to the hosted e-commerce website (to update the delivery address - note that the credit card information is not sent)
2. and on success of ajax response, the credit card form is submitted (http POST) to the payment provider

does performing the ajax in step 1 make the site non PCI compliant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'm not a QSA.

That said, because you're accepting credit card information directly on your site (even though you don't send it to your server), you need to fill out [SAQ A-EP](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/documents/SAQ_A-EP_v3.pdf).  Among the things you certify with that SAQ are:

> - All processing of cardholder data is outsourced to a PCI DSS validated third-party payment processor
> - Your e-commerce website does not receive cardholder data but controls how consumers, or their cardholder data, are redirected to a PCI DSS validated third-party payment processor
> - Your company does not electronically store, process, or transmit any cardholder data on your systems or premises, but relies entirely on a third party(s) to handle all these functions

Do note that "cardholder data" does *not* include the billing address, even though it's data about the cardholder.  In this context, it [means](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/pci_security/glossary#C):

> At a minimum, cardholder data consists of the full PAN. Cardholder data may also appear in the form of the full PAN plus any of the following: cardholder name, expiration date and/or service code.

So there's no issue with posting the address back to your own site, so long as the card information doesn't go with it.